# bootstrap-datepicker error: datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am getting an error. Upon checking other solutions they say that they declared jQuery twice, and that's why it shows. But in my case I only declared jQuery once.

Please see the code snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months",
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>My Teasting Website</title>

  <!--Bootstrap css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--bootstrap-datepicker css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap-datePicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" id = "datepicker">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>

  <!--Jquery js-->
  <script src="src/jquery.js"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap js-->
  <script src = "src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--bootstrap-datepicker js -->
  <script src="src/bootstrap-datePicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And below as you can see is my folder directories and declaration:

[image]

The error shown on the console:

[image]

Comment: It may be depending on your included jQuery-plugin. Have you already tried to write `jQuery()` instead of `$()`?

Comment: Nope not yet. Gonna try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this example [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)...

The difference in your code is that you used `id` instead of `class` in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months"
  });
})
```

Also, change the HTML:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you test this code in the Codepen, it works so the problem probably is in including scripts. If your `src` folder contains required scripts, try to change the path's from:`<script src="src/...` to `<script src="./src/...`

Comment: already changed it and still didn't work.  Btw this is where i got my download from: https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/. Also i've edited the question and inserted the file directory and my declaration.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like bootstrap-datepicker is not loaded correctly make sure your js files paths are correct, I can't really tell if the paths are correct, however, the order of loading scripts is correct. try using a CDN for jquery and bootstrap

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I've checked my declaration but still the problem is the same. I've edited the question with the new screenshot of the file directory and my declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>My Teasting Website</title>

  <!--Bootstrap css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--bootstrap-datepicker css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap-datePicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" id = "datepicker">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>

  <!--Jquery js-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months",
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
})
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is working for me, I do not see any error on my console. I just replaced your file paths with CDN. I am sure there is something wrong with your paths